# I got an error while using Scss in my Reactjs project

Tags: sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0E8n.png)[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ3Xq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gemsk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhqUC.png)

can someone help me fix the error to be able to use scss in my project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: compile the scss and import css to the file you would like to use